# Can AWS text_detection() detect Chinese or other languages in an image?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, machine-learning, ocr

I am new to python and machine-learning but I have started to grasp it. Using AWS text_detection is really cool but I am wondering whether it can detect languages other then English. I know AWS has a feature to recognize the dominant language in text files but is there recognition for image files? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am pretty sure it only recognizes English words that contain only letters from the English alphabet.

From the docs:

> A word is one or more ISO basic Latin script characters that aren't separated by spaces. DetectText can detect up to 50 words in an image.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it more.